# Assigning values to variables

Tags: java, variables

Why does this piece of code show compiling error

```
public class Foo {
    int a=5;
    a=4;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The Java language allows only member declarations in the class level, not arbitrary code.

To have 4 assigned to `a` when objects of `Foo` are created you should put the assignment either in a constructor or in an initializer block.

This is an initializer block:

```
public class Foo {
    int a = 5;
    {
        a = 4;
    }
}
```

This is a constructor:

```
public class Foo {
    int a = 5;
    public Foo() {
        a = 4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define private variables and assign values to them when they are declared, but to change it's value you will need to do it in some function.

```
 public class Foo{
       int a = 5;
       //Constructor
       void Foo(){
             a = 4;
       }
       //Normal Function
       void Change(){
             a = 4;
       }
 }
```

Hope this helps you.